# Clojure, midje: lein test - running twice

Tags: clojure, leiningen, midje

I'm just toying with midje on some project. core_test.clj:

```
(ns pcc.core-test
  (:use [clojure.repl])
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
        [clojure.string :as string]
        [green-tags.core :as core]
        [me.raynes.fs :as fs]
        [pcc.core :refer :all]
        [midje.sweet :refer :all]))

(println "You should expect to see one failure below.")

(facts
 "About miscellaneous functions"
 (fact
  "Returns a zero padded string representation of integer"
  (zero-pad 1 4) => "0001"
  (zero-pad 15111 4) => "15111"
  (zero-pad 2 5) => "00002")

 (fact
  "Returns a path stripped of extension, if any"
  (strip-file-ext "/alfa/bravo/charlie.dat") => "/alfa/bravo/charlie"
  (strip-file-ext "/alfa/bravo/charlie") => "/alfa/bravo/charlie"
  (strip-file-ext "/alfa/bravo/charlie/") => "/alfa/bravo/charlie"
  (strip-file-ext "/alfa/bra.vo/charlie.dat") => "/alfa/bra.vo/charlie"))
```

The output of **lein test**:

```
$ lein test
You should expect to see one failure below.

FAIL "About miscellaneous functions - Returns a path stripped of extension, if any" at (core_test.clj:24)
  Expected: "/alfa/bravo/charlie"
    Actual: "/alfa/bravo/charlie/"
You should expect to see one failure below.

FAIL "About miscellaneous functions - Returns a path stripped of extension, if any" at (core_test.clj:24)
Expected: "/alfa/bravo/charlie"
  Actual: "/alfa/bravo/charlie/"

lein test user

Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
$
```

It just runs twice. Curiously, the basic **lein new midje** project runs once, but I can see no substantial difference.

Comment: do you get the same result from running "lein midge"?

Comment: I found something, at least (less than half answer): there has to be just one file (core_test.clj) down your **test** directory. It would be great to know why.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/A-tutorial-introduction midje is intended to run test through `lein midje` command rather than `lein test`.

From the code you pasted you didn't need the `[clojure.test :refer :all]` on your `require`

To create a new midje test suite the correct command is `lein new midje <<projectname>>` not sure if you simply closed the *bold tag* prematurely on your post though

Hope it helps